# Datatables Checkboxes select multiple on matching ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-checkboxes

I have a server-side datatable setup with the checkboxes plugin.
Each checkbox has the data of a product_id.

```
var table = $('#display_users').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        'ajax': '{{ route ('/getUsers') }}',
        'columns' : [
            {"data" : "product_id"},
            {"data" : "product_id"},
            {"data" : "first_name"},
            {"data" : "last_name"},
            {"data" : "email"},
            {"data" : "company"},
            {"data" : "department"},
            {"data" : "created_at"}
        ],
        'columnDefs': [
            {
                'targets': 0,
                'checkboxes': {
                    'selectRow': true
                },
```

I would like to be able to, when a checkbox is selected, select all the checkboxes with the same product_id. This is only necessary for the records on the currently selected page. 
It seems this should be possible with the checkboxes select api, however I haven't been successful so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see much value in 'checkbox' plug-in as its features can be effortlessly implemented with few lines of code while giving you greater flexibility.

However, you don't really need to dig deep into 'checkbox' plug-in internals as your required feature can be easily coded with native DataTables API:

```
//listen for the clicking first column checkboxes
$('#display_users').click('tbody td:eq(0) [type="checkbox"]', function(){
  //grab current checkbox state and criteria to match (product_id) from the row data
  const state = $(event.target).prop('checked');
  const productId = dataTable.row($(event.target).closest('tr')).data().product_id;
  //iterate through current page rows and adjust checkboxes upon matching product_id
  dataTable.rows({page:'current'}).every(function(){
    if(this.data().product_id == productId) $(this.node()).find('td:eq(0) [type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', state);
  });
});
```

Complete **demo** of this concept you may find below:

```js
//data sample
const srcData = [
  {product_id: 7, first_name: 'Nick', last_name: 'Furry', company: 'Avengers Inc'},
  {product_id: 7, first_name: 'Steve', last_name: 'Rogers', company: 'Avengers Inc'},
  {product_id: 4, first_name: 'Arthur', last_name: 'Curry', company: 'Justice Ltd'},
  {product_id: 4, first_name: 'Clark', last_name: 'Kent', company: 'Justice Ltd'},
  {product_id: 4, first_name: 'Barry', last_name: 'Allen', company: 'Justice Ltd'}
];

//datatable initialization
const dataTable = $('#display_users').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  order: [1, 'asc'],
  data: srcData,
  columns: [null, ...Object.keys(srcData[0])].map(header => ({title: header || '', data: header})),
  columnDefs: [
    {targets: 0, orderable: false, render: () => '<input type="checkbox"></input>'}
  ]
});

//essential part - row checkbox click hander
$('#display_users').click('tbody td:eq(0) [type="checkbox"]', function(){
  //grab current checkbox state and criteria to match (product_id)
  const state = $(event.target).prop('checked');
  const productId = dataTable.row($(event.target).closest('tr')).data().product_id;
  //iterate through current page rows and adjust checkboxes upon matching product_id
  dataTable.rows({page:'current'}).every(function(){
    if(this.data().product_id == productId) $(this.node()).find('td:eq(0) [type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', state);
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="display_users"></table>
</body>
</html>
```